# CRM 4.0 - FetchXML to retrieve data from related entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm trying to use FetchXML to pull in a list of courses with an 'entry year' related entity.  What I would like to do is only return a single record for each course (could return multiple courses) with the latest year (e.g I would want it to pick the last year out of 2012, 2013, 2014 - so in this case 2014).  So I currently have:

```
<fetch mapping="logical" distinct="true">
    <entity name="course">
        <all-attributes/>
        <order attribute="name" />
        <link-entity name="course_entryyear" from="courseid" to="courseid">
            <link-entity name="entryyear" from="entryyearid" to="entryyearid">
                <attribute name="year" />
            </link-entity>
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Is this possible to do within FetchXML and if so how can I amend the above?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

What about adding count="1" and inner join to the linked entities along with some ordering:

So it would look like:

```
<fetch mapping="logical" distinct="true">
    <entity name="course">
        <all-attributes/>
        <order attribute="name" />
        <link-entity name="course_entryyear" from="courseid" to="courseid" link-type="inner">
            <link-entity name="entryyear" from="entryyearid" to="entryyearid" link-type="inner" count="1">
                <attribute name="year" />
                <order attribute="year" descending="true"/>
            </link-entity>
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Depending on how you are displaying the course list you might want to change the link-type for the "course-entryyear" from **inner** to **outer**, so that all courses get displayed even if they haven't been served yet.

Comment: Hi. Firstly, thank you for answering. I've tried with your code, but it still returns multiple records per course. Could it be that you can't use the count property in the link-entity?  Thanks again.

Comment: OK, damn, I only have CRM 2011 to play with so maybe the "count" attribute on linked-entities isn't supported in CRM 4, but just to test, you could try to add count="1" on the "course_entryyear" (and maybe remove the ordering in year) as well just to check if the resultset still contains multiple records per course.